# I would like to know how to get option ENABLE Bitcode in XCODE 7 beta 4?

Tags: xcode7, ios9, bitcode

I want to deploy iOS application for iOS version 5.1.1 and above with xcode 7.

But when I tried to run my iOS application project in Xcode 7 beta 4 then it shows error message 
“-fembed-bitcode is not supported on versions of iOS prior to 6.0”

And for this error I found following predictions on googling,
"Xcode 7 has a ENABLE_BITCODE option to embed bitcode in apps, app extensions, and frameworks. The option is turned on by default for iOS and is mandatory for watchOS projects submitted to the store. When bitcode is enabled for a target, all the objects, static libraries and user frameworks used when linking that target must contain bitcode. Otherwise, an error or a warning will be issued by the linker. (Note: missing bitcode is currently a warning for iOS, but it will become an error in an upcoming beta release of Xcode 7.) ENABLE_BITCODE should be consistently turned on for all the targets. If you use a library or framework provided by a third party, please contact the vendor for an updated version which contains bitcode."

Then tried to set ENABLE_BITCODE = NO in Xcode 7 beta 4 But I can’t find this option in Xcode 7 beta 4 under Build Settings of Project and Target of my iOS application project.

Please help me I would like to know how to get option ENABLE Bitcode in XCODE 7 beta 4?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you wish to deploy for iOS5.1.1, not that you won't be able to support watch OS. If you wish to support Watch OS, bitcode needs to be enabled. I would suggest you consider dropping support for iOS 5, since it is outdated now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To Show Option ENABLE_BITCODE Option in Xcode 7 Use following steps,

1) Right Click On “YourProjectName.xcodeproj” file and Select “Show Package Contents” option.

2) Open “project.pbxproj” TextEdit application and add ENABLE_BITCODE = NO; in two places in project.pbxproj file as shown below,

1D6058950D05DD3E006BFB54 /* Release */ = {/* Build configuration list for PBXNativeTarget "::APP_TITLE::" */
            isa = XCBuildConfiguration;
            buildSettings = {
                ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME = AppIcon;
                ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_LAUNCHIMAGE_NAME = LaunchImage;
                                ENABLE_BITCODE = NO;

1D6058940D05DD3E006BFB54 /* Debug */ = {/* Build configuration list for PBXNativeTarget "::APP_TITLE::" */
            isa = XCBuildConfiguration;
            buildSettings = {
                ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME = AppIcon;
                ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_LAUNCHIMAGE_NAME = LaunchImage;
                ENABLE_BITCODE = NO;

3) Save above changes in “project.pbxproj” file.

4) Open your project in Xcode 7 then you will see the option ENABLE_BITCODE under Targets => BuildSettings.

5) Set ENABLE_BITCODE = NO to Debug, Release, Distribution.

6) Build and Run your project on your device.

Answer (score 10):

This answer is a bit late, but for those who hitting this page for the first time. When you click on **Build Settings** make sure you also select **All** tab and then search for **bitcode**.

By default, **Basic** tab is selected and you wouldn't be able to find **Enable Bitcode** in the **Build Options**. Said that, if you have changed bitcode setting in the past it will show up under **Basic** tab too. As you can see from [Mark Szymczyk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/752890/mark-szymczyk) post above, **All** tab is selected.

Answer (score 4):

Typing **bitcode** in the build settings search field makes the Enable Bitcode build setting appear for me in the editor. The Enable Bitcode build setting is in the Build Options group.

[image]